# I can't do numerical operations with C language. Int variables are not assigned as I specified. randomly determined

Tags: c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int numberone;
        int numbertwo;
        int process;
        int conclusion;
    
        numberone = 0;
        numbertwo = 0;
    
        printf("Specify First Number");
        scanf("%d",&numberone);
        printf("Your first number is set (%d)\n specify the second number\n",&numberone);
        scanf("%d",&numbertwo);
        printf("your second number is set to (%d)...\n",&numbertwo);
    
        printf("Operations you can do are \n1:addition\n2:subtraction\n3:division\n4:multiplication");
        scanf("%d",&process);
    
        switch(process){
            case 1:
                conclusion=numberone+numbertwo;
                printf("The result of the addition operation %d",conclusion);
    
                break;
    
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            default:
            break;
    
        }
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

I want to make a simple calculator to learn the logic of switch-case, but as in other programs I make, int variables are very different from the ones I assign from the terminal using scanf.
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFtVj.png)

I defined the Variables in the code to zero

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the sample output *as text*, even if you already got an answer.

Comment: Unsullied, `"printf("Your first ...%d...\n",&numberone);"` was **not** the mistake - that was only 1 mistake.  Compiling with all warnings enable is _the_ mistake.  Enable them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("Your first number is set (%d)\n specify the second number\n",&numberone);
```

it should be

```
printf("Your first number is set (%d)\n specify the second number\n",numberone);
```

Otherwise, you print the reference (address) of the variable using a signed integer format which is UB.